# Teechart + Word Wrap for legend

Tags: activex, teechart

I am drawing a Trend chart(line) but in my case the legend Text is really big so it there any way that I can word wrap the text.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the string functions that  you can find in this [link](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions) to manipulate the titles of series and try to reduce their length. I have made a suggestion code that I think can help you achieve as you want:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False
    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    Dim i As Integer
    TChart1.Series(0).AddXY 0, 30, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(0).AddXY 10, 100, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(1).AddXY 0, 50, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(1).AddXY 50, 120, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(0).Title = "DDDDAAAAFFFFLLLLRRRRSSSS"
    TChart1.Series(1).Title = "AAAALLLLSSSSTTTTEEEERRRR"
    SeriesTitleWarp TChart1.SeriesCount
End Sub

Private Sub SeriesTitleWarp(ByVal count As Long)
'Replace some chars of string title to ...
    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To count - 1
            'Calculate the size of string
            Dim LenString As Integer
            LenString = Len(TChart1.Series(i).Title)
            'First replace the Left chars for ...
            Dim TitleString As String
            TitleString = TChart1.Series(i).Title
            Mid$(TitleString, 10, 3) = "..."
            'After cut the string
            TitleString = Left(TitleString, 12)
            'Assign new title to series.
            TChart1.Series(i).Title = TitleString
    Next i
End Sub
```

Revising your requirements, I suggest you an other alternative that reduces the Legend Text, but the title of series remains intact. Could you please check if next code works as you want?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False
    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    Dim i As Integer
    TChart1.Series(0).AddXY 0, 30, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(0).AddXY 10, 100, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(1).AddXY 0, 50, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(1).AddXY 50, 120, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(0).Title = "DDDDAAAAFFFFLLLLRRRRSSSS"
    TChart1.Series(1).Title = "AAAALLLLSSSSTTTTEEEERRRR"
  '  TChart1.Legend.ShapeBounds.Right = 100
    TChart1.Legend.Left = 100
    TChart1.Legend.CustomPosition = True
    TChart1.Legend.Width = 100
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnGetLegendText(ByVal LegendStyle As Long, ByVal ValueIndex As Long, LegendText As String)
        If ValueIndex <> -1 Then
            'Calculate the size of string
            Dim LenString As Integer
            LenString = Len(TChart1.Series(ValueIndex).Title)
            'First replace the Left chars for ...
            Dim TitleString As String
            TitleString = TChart1.Series(ValueIndex).Title
            Mid$(TitleString, 10, 3) = "..."
            'After cut the string
            TitleString = Left(TitleString, 12)
            'Assign new text to LegendText
            LegendText = TitleString
        End If
End Sub
```

I hope will helps.

Thanks.

Comment: If I do this it won't be returning me the entire series name when I do get legendText. Can't we specify somewhere the size of Legend Box.

Comment: Hello @AkshayBhalla,
Sorry for the delay. Isn't possible achieve cut text changing the size of Legend. For this reason, I have added an alternative solution for you in my previous answer. Please, check if it works in your end. 
Thanks, 
Sandra